# How to change text to number in query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have this query

```
SELECT SUM (pw. [Plan]) AS [Plan],
       SUM (pw.[execution]) AS [Execution],
       ([Execution] - [Plan]) AS [Deviation],
       (IIf ([Plan]> 0, [Deviation] / [Plan], 'No plan')) AS [Deviation%]...
```

The problem is when I'm using IIf the results of query in Excel are seen as text, without it it's ok. How to change it to be visible as number? Or maybe can I make condition that plan must be higher than 0 in another way?

Answer (score 1):

The return value of this expression:

```
IIf ([Plan]> 0, [Deviation] / [Plan], 'No plan')
```

is recognized as text since `'No plan'` is text.  
If both the *true* and *false* parts of `IIf` were numeric, like:

```
IIf ([Plan]> 0, [Deviation] / [Plan], 0)
```

then Excel would see the result as a number.